# How do I get a single vector for a single word using Word2Vec?

Tags: python, deep-learning, word2vec

I'm trying to solve a Deep Learning text classification problem, so I have to vectorize the text input with Word2Vec to feed it into a neural network.

So I downloaded a Google pre trained Word2Vec model: https://github.com/3Top/word2vec-api

And load it using gensim:

```
import gensim
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('Word2Vec.bin', binary=True)
```

When I try to print a specific word:

```
print(model['cat'])
# => expected output: 0.47385435 (or something)
# => actual output: array with hundreds of floats between -1 and 1
```

Why don't I just get one vector for one word? Isn't that the point?

Bonus Question: Can I load the 3M word vectors in the Google pre trained Word2Vec model into a MongoDB database? (Columns: id - word(string) - vector(float)). Because loading the model from a .bin or .txt file takes over a minute.

Comment: a vector is going to have multiple values by definition (unless you have a one dimensional vector I guess). So you do get one vector per word, its just that in this case a vector **is** an array. See the example in the docs [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.word_vec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
When I try to print a specific word:

print(model['cat'])
# => expected output: 0.47385435 (or something)
# => actual output: array with hundreds of floats between -1 and 1
Why don't I just get one vector for one word? Isn't that the point?
```

"array with hundreds of floats between -1 and 1" IS a word vector.

Why do you expect a scala (0.47385435) when you want to call a vector?

You need to read this: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec